# SQL Sever query execute

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select top(1) 
    Tb_Customer.ID 
from 
    Tb_Customer 
inner join 
    Tb_Agency_Eshterak on Tb_Customer.ID = Tb_Agency_Eshterak.CustomerID 
where 
    Tb_Agency_Eshterak.TypeE = 2 
order by
    ((convert(decimal(10), Tb_Customer.Lat) - '36.828381258846065') 
     (convert(decimal(10), Tb_Customer.Lat) - '36.828381258846065')) + 
    ((convert(decimal(10), Tb_Customer.Lng) - '54.454983147717144') 
     (convert(decimal(10), Tb_Customer.Lng) - '54.454983147717144')) ASC
```

Does this query have any problems?
I Cant Excute it In Sql Server 
This Is Emergency Thanks

Comment: what problem are you facing ?

Comment: Try to provide the error, you are facing.

Comment: No idea what that order by is supposed to be as there are missing operators. Also, the convert decimal(10) will remove all the decimals. Is that what you want. Finally, if you are ordering by this, then the subtracting a constant will have no effect and can be left out.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing paranthesis`)`. You are missing operators in your `ORDER BY` clause. I have put multiplication operator, to make the query compile. Also, it is not recommended to have this big expression in the `ORDER BY` clause.
I would suggest you to have a [persisted computed column](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1682/using-computed-columns-in-sql-server-with-persisted-values/) and use that column in your `ORDER BY` clause.

```
select top(1) Tb_Customer.ID 
from Tb_Customer 
inner join Tb_Agency_Eshterak
on Tb_Customer.ID=Tb_Agency_Eshterak.CustomerID 
where Tb_Agency_Eshterak.TypeE=2 
ORDER BY
((CONVERT(decimal(10),Tb_Customer.Lat)-'36.828381258846065') * (CONVERT(decimal(10),Tb_Customer.Lat)-'36.828381258846065')) + ((CONVERT(decimal(10),Tb_Customer.Lng) - '54.454983147717144') * (CONVERT(decimal(10),Tb_Customer.Lng) - '54.4549831477171'))
```